# Bounded second derivative implies $|f(a)| \leq C(1+|a|^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ be a twice differentiable function such that $0 < A \leq f''(x) \leq B$ for all $x$. Then there exists a $C>0$ such that $|f(x)| \leq C(1+|x|^2)$.

---

I have tried this and gotten a linear growth bound on the first derivative but then applying this same method again gives me something like $|f(x)|\leq C(1+x+x^2)$. I am not sure how to eliminate the first order term.

Comment: Try integrating the given inequality to find some more useful conditions on $f$ itself.

Comment: I have tried this and gotten a linear growth bound on the first derivative but then applying this same method again gives me something like $|f(x)| \leq C(1 + x + x^2)$. I am not sure how to eliminate the first order term

Comment: @ben: $|x| \leq \max(1,x^2)$